# foreign ssh login I don't recognize

Tags: ssh, ip, attack-vector

The last ssh login to my server was seemingly from a computer I don't recognize.
How can I found out who that was?
aaubervilliers-651-1-60-191.w83-200.abo.wanadoo.fr

I'm not in France!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some information can be found using the `last` command (I am assuming you have a Linux server).

More information are located in `/var/log/auth.log`: there you can find which user logged into the system from that Wanadoo host (which IP address can be obtained issuing the command `host aaubervilliers-651-1-60-191.w83-200.abo.wanadoo.fr`)

Answer (score 0):

Short of contacting Wanadoo in France, there's very little you can do.

In the meantime, strengthen your passwords and then install and configure DenyHosts (http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/). It's a standard package for distributions such as Debian, Ubuntu,  and I believe Gentoo.